# Prononciation de « plasma »

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

Je ne connaissais que la prononciation [plasma], par exemple donnée par le [Trésor de la langue française](http://atilf.atilf.fr/).
En écoutant l'excellent [Cédric Villani](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9dric_Villani) parler, par exemple [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSeybpMJy_0), je découvre la prononciation [plazma]. Celle-ci peut être induite par le voisement de la voyelle précédente (-a) et de la consonne suivante (m-), mais je suis surpris de n'avoir jamais entendu ladite prononciation.

Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Comment: N'est-ce pas un [exemple](http://www.bang.vn/ezupload/06-12-2011/an-introduction-to-french-pronunciation-1323155094.pdf#page=134&zoom=auto,-160,481) de [l'assimilation](http://www.linguistes.com/phonetique/assimilation.htm) [régressive](http://www.nou.edu.ng/uploads/NOUN_OCL/pdf/pdf2/FINAL%20FRE%20331.pdf#page=72&zoom=auto,-159,513) ?

Answer (score 10):

En violation de la règle de prononciation standard du s suivi d'une consonne qui est sensé garder le son /s/, on entend parfois /z/ dans « plasma ».

Voici quelques mots présentant aussi, plus ou moins souvent, parfois toujours, cette prononciation qui ne pose bien sûr aucun problème d'ambiguïté ou de compréhension, les sons étant très proches et les paires minimales absentes:

- absentéisme
- alcoolisme
- athlétisme
- capitalisme
- casbah<sup>*</sup>
- cataplasme
- cosmos
- cyclisme
- esgourde
- fantasme
- fascisme
- féminisme
- frisbee
- Israël
- miasme
- nasdaq
- orgasme
- pléonasme
- presbyte<sup>*</sup>
- rosbif<sup>*</sup>
- sarcasme
- sbire<sup>*</sup>
- Tasmanie
- terrorisme

Beaucoup de ces mots utilisent le suffixe -isme dont [l'entrée dans le tlfi contient cette remarque](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-isme):

*Prononc. et Orth. : [-ism]. **Dialectal (notamment Midi de la France, Alsace) ou par affectation (radio, télévision) : [-izm]***

[L'OQLF a une position plus souple](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2510):

*La prononciation régulière des mots qui se terminent par -isme, par exemple communisme, barbarisme, régionalisme, est [ism] (ism). **Toutefois, la prononciation [izm] (izm) n’est pas considérée comme fautive et elle s’explique phonétiquement.***

Sur lexique.org, la prononciation /izm/ pour la terminaison -isme [**est largement majoritaire**](http://www.lexique.org/moteur/complexe.php?regex=1&nom_champs%5B1%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B1%5D=&champs%5B1%5D=.*isme%24&nom_champs%5B2%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B2%5D=&champs%5B2%5D=&nom_champs%5B3%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B3%5D=&champs%5B3%5D=&nom_champs%5B4%5D=lexique3.ortho&like%5B4%5D=&champs%5B4%5D=&tri=RAND%28%29&sens=ASC&pers%5B0%5D=*&pers%5B0%5D=lexique3.ortho&pers%5B1%5D=lexique3.phon&pers%5B2%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B3%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B4%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&pers%5B5%5D=Non_Sp%E9cifi%E9&database=lexique.lexique3&lienbdd=&Rechercher=Rechercher&nblignes=500&format=html).

<sup>*</sup> Prononciation avec /z/ indiquée dans les dictionnaires.

Comment: Je suis curieux de savoir comment à tu trouvé cette liste. Liste personnelle ou internet (mais dans ce cas quels mots clés ??) ?

Comment: Ne trouvant pas (rapidement) sur Internet de document à ce sujet, j'ai construit moi-même cette liste en recherchant tous les mots où s est précédé d'une voyelle et suivi d'une consonne puis en éliminant petit à petit les combinaisons où un /z/ n'est jamais entendu (ex: st, squ, sr, sph, sl, etc.).

Comment: Effectivement, ce genre de son est dû à la proximité d'un `s` à une consonne voisée, mais n'est pas désirable.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Ce n'est pas désirable par qui ? L'harmonie de voisement entre obstruantes en contact est un phénomène qui touche la plupart des langues du monde.

Comment: @GAMPUB J'entends par là que le mot est supposé se prononcer avec un /s/ selon les normes de prononciation du français et que la prononciation en /z/ n'est qu'un effet secondaire. On ne devrait pas faire exprès de prononcer /z/. Mais ce n'est pas la fin du monde :)

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Ok. Et du coup, comment prononcez-vous *absent* ?

Comment: @GAMPUB Je le prononce également ab/s/ent. Mais je crois que c'est également une question d'accent et de régionalisation. Au Québec, la vocalisation d'un s en /z/ est très peu fréquente. Dans toute la liste de cette réponse, il n'y a que quelques mots que j'entends couramment prononcés avec un /z/.

Comment: Ma question portait en fait sur le "b" de *absent*.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Il est curieux que bien que cette vocalisation soit très peu fréquente au Québec, l'Office québécois de la langue française considère cette prononciation comme correcte pour -isme alors que bien qu'elle soit courante en France, le tlfi la considére comme dialectale ou affectée. À propos d'absent, le b y est très souvent inconsciemment prononcé comme un p, comme le c d'anecdote peut devenir un g ou le d de médecin un t.